# inf/-inf introduced when opening nc files with raster?

Tags: raster, error, netcdf

I am currently working with .nc files and have been struggling - I followed several tutorials and looked into the questions & answers here, but there remains one problem:

I can open and use (/plot etc) the .nc files with raster, however the min and max values in my new raster layer get set to inf and -inf, which leads to problems in my following steps.

When using this:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

example <- raster("myfile.nc", varname="FAPAR")
```

I get a "fully functioning" Formal Class Rasterlayer, however when looking at

```
example@data@min
example@data@max
```

I get "Inf"/"-Inf"...

Does someone know why and "when" this happens? And what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum and maximum values that are stored in `@data` are read from the metadata of the raster. Not all rasters have this information included. So if it is missing the default values are `Inf` and `-Inf`. There are several functions that can compute the minimum and maximum values, see `minValue` and `maxValue` in the `raster` package. The `setMinMax` function will populate the min and max slots within the `@data` class, although these won't be permanent unless you write a new raster out.

```
example <- raster("myfile.nc", varname="FAPAR")
example@data@min
example@data@max
example <- setMinMax(example)
example@data@min
example@data@max
```